# How to use getSupportedVideoSizes() on Android?

Tags: android, video, camera, resolution, video-capture

Im trying to record video, but it records at very low resolution.

I know that for set a video resolution I do a something like this:

`MediaRecorder recorder; recorder.setVideoSize(int width, int height);`

Ok, but I want to get the Video Resolutions supported by the device and set to `recorder.setVideoSize(int width, int height);`

I know that I can get it using `getSupportedVideoSizes()` but really I dont have idea about how to get the video resolutions and do something that show me those video resolutions and choose and then set it to `recorder.setVideoSize(int width, int height);`

Please help me, I have tried to understand a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following snippet:

```
CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
recorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
```